# how to scroll tableview in android

Tags: android, tableview, scrollview

I have an tableview which i want to scroll, because the data is not shown complete.

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4"
            android:id="@+id/maintable" >
</TableLayout>
```

this is my tablelayout, and if i wrap it in an `<ScrollView> </Scrollview>` the Application crashs if i open the activity. How to do that?

Comment: android Listview directly took scroll when list bigger then size so have you ever try to put many rows in table view???

Comment: No, i thought i have to use the tablelayout for this? because i only show a table?  ^^

Comment: can you put your full xml file?

Comment: this is the complete xml file, i fill the rows per code!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should really put the code you tried that crashed your application and the reason for your crash. There's no valuable information in your original post.

Ehhh... did you try something as simple as this? Example .xml that I use a few places:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/score_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/header"/>                    
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Works absolutely fine for me. You don't have to include the TableRow if you have no use for it, obviously.

Comment: this will scrol hole table i cannot want to scrol header then?

Answer (score 2):

Create your rows dynamically 
Here I am putting a small example,

**main.xml**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Add row"></Button>

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="0">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="textfield 1-1"></TextView>

      <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Activity is**

```
public class tablelayout extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    //initialize a button and a counter
    Button btn;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // setup the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // add a click-listener on the button
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);        

    }

    // run when the button is clicked
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // get a reference for the TableLayout
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);

        // create a new TableRow
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        // count the counter up by one
        counter++;

        // create a new TextView
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        // set the text to "text xx"
        t.setText("text " + counter);

        // create a CheckBox
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox(this);

        // add the TextView and the CheckBox to the new TableRow
        row.addView(t);
        row.addView(c);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }
}
```

You can create your table row, when in your code require. I assumed it is on button click.

Hope this will help.

And here one more [example](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=307).

Comment: No, thats not the problem, ill get my table like i want. i used this: [link](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/). But it shows not everything on screen, so i want to scroll, but thats not working

Comment: Can you explain which part not displaying, is horizontally or vertically?

Comment: And one more thing, if you want to scroll, your table must be in scroll view.